# Many-to-many relation filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo, relational-division

I need to filter my query with categories table which has many2many relation with another table. Is it possible to filter query with many2many relation?

Table `res_partner` has many2many field `category_id` relating to table `res_partner_category.res_partner`, or let's just say partners can have many categories. What I need is to filter `res_partners` table where it has category named 'business' or 'retail'. If it doesn't have any of these categories, it should not be shown.

Also there is another field in `res_partner` which is `category_value_ids` and has `one2many` relation with `res_partners_category_value`:

**`res_partner`** has following fields with relations:

- `category_id` to `res_partner_category` (many2many)
- `category_value_ids` to `res_partner_category_value` (one2many)
- `name` (char)

**`res_partner_category`** has following fields with relations:

- `partner_ids` to `res_partner` (many2many)
- `name` (char)

**`res_partner_category_value`** has following fields with relations:

- `category_group_id` to `res_partner_category` (many2one)
- `category_id` to `res_partner_category` (many2one)
- `object_id` to`res_partner` (many2one)

But if I try to use `res_partner_category_value` table in SQL query I get error that I can't use it in query.

So for example, if there are 4 partners with these categories:

- first: categ1, categ2, business
- second: retail
- third: retail, business
- fourth: categ1, categ2

The query should return first, second and third partners.
One person told me it's not possible to filter like this with many2many relation. So I wonder is it really not possible or just complicated?

EDIT:
I found one more table called `res_partner_category_rel`. I didn't see it, because in Openerp administration interface, where you can see all objects of database, that table is not shown. You can only see it directly through database.
So I was confused by this "missing" table:

**res_partner_category_rel:**

- `partner_id` (many2one)
- `category_id` (many2one)

Comment: I'm confused by the fields in each table.  For a many-to-many relationship between tables A and B, neither A nor B should have foreign key fields that point to records in the other table.  Instead there should be a separate table, C, that contains pairs of foreign key fields (1 for A, 1 for B). But from your description, `res_partner` contains a `category_id` field...  Why?

Comment: @ j_random_hacker That's an OpenERp feature: you can define a many2many "field" from A to B, and the relation table C is automatically (automagically?) managed by the ORM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Setup

This is the test case you should have provided:

```sql
CREATE TABLE partner (
  partner_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, partner    text
);
INSERT INTO partner (partner) VALUES 
  ('partner1')
, ('partner2')
, ('partner3')
, ('partner4')
;

CREATE TABLE category (
  category_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, category    text
);
INSERT INTO category (category) VALUES 
  ('categ1')
, ('categ2')
, ('business')
, ('retail')
;

CREATE TABLE partner_category (
  partner_id  int REFERENCES partner(partner_id)
, category_id int REFERENCES category(category_id)
, CONSTRAINT cat_pk PRIMARY KEY (partner_id, category_id)
);
INSERT INTO partner_category (partner_id, category_id) VALUES 
  (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)
, (2,4)
, (3,3), (3,4)
, (4,1), (4,2);
```

#### Solution

One way:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   partner p
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM partner_category pc WHERE pc.partner_id = p.partner_id AND pc.category_id = 3)
OR     EXISTS (SELECT FROM partner_category pc WHERE pc.partner_id = p.partner_id AND pc.category_id = 4)
ORDER  BY p.partner_id;
```

Another:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM        (SELECT partner_id FROM partner_category WHERE category_id = 3) pc1
FULL   JOIN (SELECT partner_id FROM partner_category WHERE category_id = 4) pc2 USING (partner_id)
JOIN   partner p USING (partner_id)
ORDER  BY p.partner_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q1MO2O23)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2870a/1)</sub>

The second one assumes unique `(partner_id, category_id)` in `partner_category`.

Comment: Well actually there is no such table as category and partner_category do not have field `partner_id`. Your query looks good, but too bad I can't use it, because tables relations are a bit different in openerp... It has relations like I written.

Comment: @oerp: If your tables are structurally different, then I suggest you update the question with a setup like I demonstrated. So people trying to help have something to work with. However, as long as we are, in fact, dealing with an m:n relationship, my example should hold.

Comment: Also at 'and category_id=3', shouldn't it be 'and pc.category_id=3'?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really solved now, when I found one table that didn't show up:)

Comment: @oerp: Well, yes, `category_id = 3`, should be `pc.category_id = 3`. It works either way - without table-qualification, the scope default to `pc` within the subquery. But for readability I ammended it. Cool that it works for you now. :)

Answer (score 2):

As you already noticed, the many2one `category_id` is not represented in the database as a table field, but as a table relating Partners and Categories.

The SQL you need could look like this:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM res_partner p
  INNER JOIN res_partner_category_rel rel ON p.id = rel.partner_id
    INNER JOIN res_partner_category c ON rel.category_id = c.id
WHERE c.id in (3,4)
```

If you want to do the filter in the python object, the usual `search`call should work:

```
list_ids = partner_model.search(cr, uid, [('category_id', 'in', [3,4])])
```

As a bonus, since Categories are organized in a tree, you could get those categories and all their children using:

```
list_ids = partner_model.search(cr, uid, [('category_id', 'child of', [3,4])])
```